# Pass product name to a form

Tags: wordpress, forms, button, woocommerce, product

I'm developing a website on Wordpress.
With WooCommerce I have some products, in the single product page I have a button that is linked to a page with a form for.
I have the necessity to pass the name of the product on the input field of the subject.

Is it possible in some way to
pass this information from the product page to the form?

Comment: If a customer clicks the product that information should be on the form?

Comment: only the name of the product in the subject. (es. subject: request information for Product1)

Comment: you can use [Product CSV Importer and Exporter](https://woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-importer-exporter/). Or if a customer orders a product and you just need the product name, you can disable fields which you dont want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Francesco _ If you add the woocommerce tag to your post it may help others asking the same or similar question ; )